# How to poll server for new posts in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a page of posts ordered by date published (most recent first):

```
$query = new WP_Query( $my_args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            the_title();
        }
    }
```

My aim now is to poll the server for new posts and if any exist they are inserted at top of the page. Any readers viewing the page of posts would then see the new posts appear at the top of the list of posts (without the need for a page refresh). My first thought was to use AJAX, then I heard about the new WP Heartbeat API.

How should I poll the server every 60 seconds and display the new data on screen without the need for a page reload? Please note I'm not asking for specific code, instead I'm trying to find out the most appropriate way of getting this done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials or other off-site resources aren't a great fit. Just searching for 'wordpress heartbeat api' throws up a few good tutorials. Also, this has already been asked here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32377/automatically-pull-newer-posts-and-append-to-current-page - those answers should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I was more interested in what is the most appropriate approach for me to take in this particular case. I'll remove the line asking for a tutorial

Comment: Even now, the question is too broad/primarily opinion based. You need to try something first then post a specific, code-related question if it doesn't work. I'd recommend using the code from the question I posted as it should work perfectly for you. If the performance is poor or you can't get it to work properly then post a question and include the code you've written. Don't mean to be a pain but otherwise you're probably not going to get any answers.

Comment: *"what is the most appropriate approach for me to take in this particular case."* That is up to you to decide. There are several approaches to choose from, some better than others, some more complex, simpler, etc.

Comment: Right, now I see there isn't a standard approach. Thanks for your comments, i'll take what you've said on board and give it a try